# css menu styling

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with some CSS trying to give my drop down table some 1 px solid black line after each element in the drop down menu. This is what my menu looks like now

[image: current]

this is what I want it to look like except I put `border: 1px solid black;` this line in the .menu li a { } but I don't want it to apply to the draft button it has a double border in this picture.

How can I fix this?

[image]

**code for the drop down element in the picture.**

---

```
.menu .dropdown_1col {
    margin:4px auto;
    left:-999em;

    position:absolute;
    background:#F4F4F4;
     border: 1px solid black;
    text-indent:15px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EEEEEE, #BBBBBB);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#EEEEEE), to(#BBBBBB));
}
```

---

```
   .menu li {
        float:left;
        text-align:center;
        position:relative;
        padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
        margin-right:30px;
        margin-top:7px;
        border:none;

    }
    .menu li:hover {
        z-index:2;
        background:#F4F4F4;
        border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
        padding: 4px 9px 4px 9px;


        /* CSS 3 Stylings */

        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F4F4F4, #EEEEEE);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#F4F4F4), to(#EEEEEE));

    }
    .menu li a {
        color: #EEEEEE;
        outline:0;
        text-decoration:none;
        display:block;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;


    }
    .menu li:hover a {
        color:#161616;
        text-shadow: none;
    }
    .menu li .drop {
        padding-right:21px;
        background:url("img/drop.png") no-repeat right 8px;
    }
    .menu li:hover .drop {
        padding-right:21px;
        background:url("img/drop.png") no-repeat right 7px;
    }
    .menu li:hover div a {
        color:#444;
    }
    .menu li:hover div a:hover {
        color:#777;
    }
    .menu li ul li a:hover {
        color:#777;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML for the menu?

Answer (score 2):

Change to:

```
{
    .........
    border: 1px 0px solid #aaaaaa;
    .........
}
```

This way you will set width of the vert and horz borders separately. You cab also play around by specifying individual `border-top` `border-left`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the problem you can try this:

***CSS CODE***

```
    .menu li a{
      border:none;
    }
```

***Else***

```
   .menu li{
      border:none;
    }
```

i.e you have to stop one of them. please apply one. If you use .menu li border then you don't need to use border for .menu li a or vice-versa.

Comment: unfortunately that did not fix it, i'm only applying a border on .menu li a { }